# KAFKA Consumer in Xamarin Android app

Tags: xamarin, apache-kafka

Can any one guide me how to consume KAFKA messages in Xamarin Android app? 
I have used KAFKA consumer in windows platform as an window service which constantly reads KAFKA messages on a topic.Now i have to write same in Xamarin android.

Comment: I would discourage mobile devices reading from a Kafka topic due to network instability and battery drain. You can send Kafka data to a database which mobile devices query periodically

Comment: Completely agree from you. Still how can i implement it?

Comment: Which one? If you absolutely want to consume in Xamarin, have you tried anything yet like adding a c# Kafka library to your project and implementing anything? What errors are you getting when you do that?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have tried by adding c# library works fine in  UWP but in android giving me error of loading native library..can you help it out of this